# Accessing the 2-D array( integer and character array)

Tags: c++11

Please consider below code:

```
char arr[3][10]={"white","red","blue"};
cout<<arr[2];  //output 1
int brr[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
cout<<brr[2];  //output 2

cout<<*brr[2];
```

Output 1 : white, on dereferencing it gives w as output

Output 2 : hexadecimal address(0x28.....)

Output 3 : Last row first element 7

I am confused why there is difference in output in array of integers and characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you supply a pointer it will use the [`std::ostream& operator<<( const void* value );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overload and output the address pointed at by `value`.

The difference is that [`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char* s)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is a special case and it will dereference `s` and output the `char`s until a `\0` is encountered. As long as no `\0` is encountered, it'll step `s` forward.