# Why does printing a char pointer and an int pointer have a different result?

Tags: c++

```
const char* arr[3];

arr[0] = "Hello";
arr[1] = "C++";
arr[2] = "World";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << arr[i];
}
int* pInt[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    pInt[i] = &i;
    cout << pInt[i] << endl;
}
```

I saved char address into the array(`arr`) and the output was `HelloC++World`.
The second time I saved int address into the array(`pInt`) and the Output was Address. Why is it different?

Comment: Focus the title on the *problem*. Learning is fine, but it's not as important as the issue at hand.

Comment: Does [Accessing the 2-D array( integer and character array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64629405/accessing-the-2-d-array-integer-and-character-array) answer your question?

Comment: Tip: `const char* arr[] = { "Hello", "C++", "World" };` Even better, learn about [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then you can do `for (auto& s : arr)` and it's super easy.

Comment: The stream insertion operator, `<<`, treats pointers to `char` as "C-style" strings. This is why `cout << "Hello";` prints "Hello" and not a numerical address.

Comment: Note that in C++, in most situations, you rather want to use `std::string` than char arrays.

Comment: If you ask a question, please provide a [mre]. Why can't you manually figure out what the correct result of `lengthOfLongestSubstring()` for the string "abcabcbb" shall be? Also, Leetcode gives you the example, tells you the solution and even explains why the output 3 is correct.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is it different?

Because there is a special [`std::ostream::operator<<(const char *)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) overload, that prints the content of the bytes the `const char *` points to.

There is no `std::ostream::operator<<(int *)`, so compiler chooses a different one. Compiler chooses to do implicit promotions from `int *` to `void *` and [`std::ostream::operator<<(const void *)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is chosen to print the value. That `operator<<(const void *)` prints the pointer address in some implementation defined format.

If you want to print the address of a `const char *` pointer, explicitly cast it to `void*`, like `std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(arr[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

Here `pInt[n]` is an `int*`, or an integer pointer. You're assigning an address (`&i`) and as such it prints an address.

If you want to print that value you'd need to do `*pInt[i]` to *de-reference* the pointer.

Comment: Of course your explanation is correct, but probably OP's confusion origins in noticing how also `char *` are addresses. Probably they need to understand that null-terminated strings are interpreted by `cout` in a special way.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I like Kamil's answer for that aspect of the question.

Comment: It's a shame, as you came first! :)